# Mustache.js does not refresh cache

Tags: javascript, caching, mustache

I have a script that calls Mustache.render a few times.

For example:

```
var data = {
    name1: "value",
    name2: "value"
}
var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
```

Then I update the data variable.
For example:

```
data.name1 = "different value";
// try and render template again
var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
```

When I try and render again, the result template shows the old data from the Mustache cache, in my case for name1 the value will be "value".

Is there a way I can clean the Mustache cache, or just get it to render the new data, or is there something I am doing wrong which would in turn cause it to use the old data and not the new one?

Comment: Why not just create a new var data1 = { name1: "different value" } and render the new data?